# My Buttons are not working after using fetch api along with express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have strange problem with buttons that are requesting for displaying templates on client page.

This is client side code. The main task of entire class is to just enable user to click button, send request and get response with HTML that has been rendered from handlebars template and just paste it in partiuclar place on client side. It works, but only once. After first click and displaying elements, I totally lose any interaction with those buttons. There is no request, and there is no even EventListener for clicking. I get no error. Completely there is no single reaction after clicking.

```
 class Weapons {
        constructor() {
            this.buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.type')
        }
    
        async displayWeapon(path) {
    
            const container = document.querySelector('.shop-container')
    
            await fetch(`weapons/${path}`).then(response => response.json()).then(data => container.innerHTML += data);
    
    
        }
    
        chooseWeapon() {
    
            this.buttons.forEach(btn => {
                btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                    console.log('click');
    
                    let weaponType = e.target.dataset.type
                    switch (weaponType) {
                        case 'pistols':
                            console.log('click');
                            return this.displayWeapon(weaponType)
    
                        case 'rifles':
                            console.log('click');
                            return this.displayWeapon(weaponType)
    
                        case 'grenades':
                            console.log('click');
    
                           return this.displayWeapon(weaponType)
    
                        case 'closerange':
                            console.log('click');
                           return this.displayWeapon(weaponType)
    
                        case 'rocketlauchner':
                            console.log('click');
                          return  this.displayWeapon(weaponType)
    
                    }
    
                })
            })
    
        }
    
    }
    
    
    
    
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    
        const weapons = new Weapons();
        weapons.chooseWeapon();
        

> When I invoke displayWeapon(path) here it also works, but immidiately
> after displaying html elements clicking on buttons again does not
> initiate any action.

    
    
    
    })
```

Here is app.get function but I doubt it's source of problem.

```
    app.get('/weapons/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req');
    console.log(req.url);

    let type = req.params.id;
    res.render(type, function (err, html) {

        res.json(html);
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi, can you try to wrap your await code in a try..catch block? See if you catch any errors in the client that way.

Comment: There is nothing. The most weird thing is I dont event get this "click" in console.log (from chooseWeapon()) function... Only with first click, and then just nothing

Comment: The problem is exactly with this fetch function. Because when I delete it I can console log 'click" after every single click. EDIT : I see now in console, that after executing fetch, there is no single event in those buttons. I lose it in some way during displying data in html "container"

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out. Good job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The answer is actually simple. In fetch function `container.innerHTML += data.` This line deletes my html with buttons, and the same time it deletes eventListeners. So I need just to modify my html.